# Can't send data with ajax to a asp.net mvc controller

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, cross-domain

Hello i'm having problems sending data through ajax to my asp.net controller. When i try to view the problem in opera inspector i get server 500 error on jquery line 8720.
xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );
Here are my code samples:
Html:

```
      <div class="top-row">
            <div class="field-wrap">

                    <label>
                        <span class="req"></span>
                    </label>
                    <input class="text-center" type="text" required autocomplete="off"  name="url" id="url" />

            </div>


          </div>



          <button type="submit" class="button button-block" name="sendIT" id="sendIT">Save</button>



        </div>
```

Javascript:

```
var button1 = document.getElementById("sendIT");
function LoginButton1OnClick() {
    var text = $('#url').val();
    alert(text);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Book/TestBook',
        crossDomain: true,
        data: text,
        success: function () {
            alert('success');
        }, error: function (data) {
            alert("Error");  
        }
    });
}
button1.addEventListener("click", LoginButton1OnClick);

C#:
```

`[HttpPost]`enter code here
            `public ActionResult  TestBook(string test)
            {
                var s1 = test;
                return View();
            }`

Comment: Try data: JSON.stringify({teste: text})

Comment: yes that was the problem it seems you can send objects only for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error 500 you're getting is because of the malformed 'data' in your ajax POST request. You need to send the data as an object:

**Javascript**

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Home/TestBook',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({test: text }),
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success');
        }, error: function (data) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
```

Note that the "test" parameter in javascript needs to mach the exact same name in your controller.

Comment: Does your ajax call end up falling into your controller? Did you debug?

Comment: Eh sorry i forgot to remove the last parenthesis in my old javascript file, your solution is working.But still i would like to know why does my solution wont send data to the controller as well. Can you elaborate maybe

Comment: See my updated answer. I've created a test project to emulate your case.

Comment: Don't understand why the downvote here. Could you care to explain, please?

Comment: i did not down vote.... Anyway although the function is send data to the controller still i get the error alert later on. You know why

Comment: I know it wasn't way :) Relax with the downvote, I've moved on. You are probably getting error because you are returning a View. I never had to do that, but in my test project it happened too. Perphaps you can change the return to a JsonResult and return something like success = true to indicate the post went Okay. And don't forget to use the AllowGet to allow MVC to return json.

Answer (score 1):

you need to post data as object

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Book/TestBook',
    crossDomain: true,
    data: {test: text},
    success: function () {
        alert('success');
    }, error: function (data) {
        alert("Error");  
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah it works... didn't know you must send objects only. Thanks